# Как сделать цикличиский сдвиг двумерного массива на n элементов вниз и вправо через if С++

Tags: c++

cout << "Where does the matrix shift - to the right(0), down(1) ? " << endl;

```
int a;
cin >> a;
if (a == 0)
{
    cin >> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            temp = arr[j][0];
            for (int g = 0; g < m - 1; g++)          // условие для смещения  влево
                arr[j][g] = arr[j][g + 1];
            arr[j][m - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример. Смещение вправо ещё понятно. А что в вашем варианте значит смещение вниз? Как это выглядит?

Comment: Матрица: 
   1:2:3:4:5:6
    7:8:9:0:10
     3:9:3:4:1
Выбираем сдвиг вниз:
На сколько сдвигаем: на 2 например 
и результат: 
     7:8:9:0:10
     3:9:3:4:1
    1:2:3:4:5:6
Или же на 1:
    3:9:3:4:1
   1:2:3:4:5:6
    7:8:9:0:10
     
Можете в код вписать еще свдиг впрво, чтобы было и в низ и в право

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (std::size_t j = cols - 1; j > 0; --j)//right
        std::swap(arr[0][j], arr[0][j - 1]);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows - 1; ++i)//down
        std::swap(arr[i][0], arr[i + 1][0]);
```

С остальным как-нибудь сами.

**P.S**: rows -> строки, cols -> столбцы

Comment: Понял, спасибо тебе большое